# Guidance for a data logger and radio

Tags: security, hardware

I've currently been working with a consultant, whom recommended we utilize an architecture that is based off the Microchip ATMELAVR 8 bit Arduino framework.  The board is called a Mayfly, picture below:

[image]

Currently one of our configuration would use digital pins (D10-D12), I2C, header stack for digital pins (D4-D11, D18-D21, D23), power, SDA, SCL, Sw3, and Sw5.  The pins near the USB support our cellular radio.

I'm hoping to leverage Microsoft's Azure IoT Hub, which requires a ESP32 to leverage their SDK.  I'd like to ensure I could do cellular or LoRa WAN, with our existing communication including leveraging Modbus.  The board I found [Azure IoT Development Board](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/ESP32-AZURE+IOT+KIT/1965-ESP32-AZUREIOTKIT-ND/10259357?itemSeq=342586326).  Would this work?  And any recommendations for radios?

- Multitech mDot LoRa WAN or Digi LTE cellular radio
- Ultra sonic level sensor (D10-D11)
- Soil Moisture Sensors (I2C)
- Water Quality (pH, ORP, DO, Conductivity, Turbidity) with Modbus Wing / Shield (upping voltage to 9 volts to power all sensors) on the entire header stack above I2C port.

A picture of a sample station working with the above sensors (except soil moisture):

[image]

The problem, the Mayfly cannot connect to Azure due to security issues.  Cannot broadcast SSL/TLS.  Our organization currently leverages the consultants entire suite, but we want to harden and begin to pull our data collected to our system natively rather than through API's.